# Python CGIServer is not redirecting to index.html

Tags: python, cgi

I have the following script as my CGI Server:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  ## This line enables CGI error reporting

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8600)
handler.cgi_directories = ['']

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And I have a file named "index.html", which is symlinked to the "main.cgi" executable inside the directory in which the server is running. However, it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on other examples I've seen you could try this:

```
handler.cgi_directories = ["/"]
```

in your code instead of `handler.cgi_directories = ['']`